# Reading Crash Logs

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

I recently released my app on the Play Store and it has come to my attention that is is crashing on certain devices. I've tested it on multiple myself and there was no issue at all.

I don't have much experience with reading the logs, and I can't quite figure out the issue myself. I understand that the error is in a certain location, but how can I tell what is causing this error?

Here is the code from the class where the error is happening:

```
package com.apps.robloxmusic;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout musicCodes;
    private LinearLayout twitterCodes;
    private LinearLayout artistSearch;
    private LinearLayout discordOpen;
    private LinearLayout categorySearch;
    private LinearLayout websiteOpen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        //Init Mobile Ads
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"XXXXXXXXXXX");

        //Dashboard ---> Music Codes
        musicCodes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.musicCodesButton);
        musicCodes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMusicCodes();
            }
        });

        //Dashboard ---> Twitter Codes
        twitterCodes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.twitterCodesButton);
        twitterCodes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openTwitterCodes();
            }
        });

        //Dashboard ---> Artists
        artistSearch = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.artistSearchButton);
        artistSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openArtistSearch();
            }
        });

        //Dashboard ---> Discord Link
        discordOpen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.discordServerButton);
        discordOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openDiscord();
            }
        });

        //Dashboard ---> Categories
        categorySearch = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.categorySearchButton);
        categorySearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openCategorySearch();
            }
        });

        //Dashboard ---> Website Link
        websiteOpen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.websiteButton);
        websiteOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openWebsite();
            }
        });

    }
    //Methods for Activity changes
    public void openMusicCodes() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openTwitterCodes() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwitterViewer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openArtistSearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Artists.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openDiscord() {
        String url = "https://discord.gg/QESMn66";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openCategorySearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Categories.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openWebsite() {
        String url = "http://rocodes.io";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2572)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2654)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1488)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at com.apps.robloxmusic.Dashboard.onCreate (Dashboard.java:26)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6309)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1113)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2519)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:2922)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2844)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:870)
  at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4001)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:604)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init> (FrameLayout.java:115)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:185)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:181)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.<init> (ScrollView.java:177)
```

Layout file for the class in question:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dashbg"
    tools:context=".Dashboard">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Dashboard"
                        android:id="@+id/dashTextMain"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dashTextSub"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#E8E8E8"
                android:text="Welcome to RoCodes.io,"
                android:layout_below="@id/dashTextMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashTextSub2"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#E8E8E8"
                    android:text="your home for Roblox codes!"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dashTextSub"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/robcodescropped"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        <GridLayout
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/musicCodesButton"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@drawable/musicicon"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:text="Music Codes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/artistSearchButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/artisticon"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Search Artists"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/categorySearchButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/categoryicon"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Music Categories"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/discordServerButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/discordicon"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="RoCodes Discord"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/twitterCodesButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/twittericon"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="New Codes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/websiteButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/websiteicon"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="RoCodes Website"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I'm really at a loss for what is wrong here. It works fine on all of my devices.

Comment: _Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException_ - Check your resources.

Comment: All of the resources appear to be there. It works on the few devices I've tried without any problems, as well as my friends devices. If a resource was missing wouldn't this error be across all devices?

Comment: check you have resources in main drawable folder if you have put resources to support multiple configs.

Comment: Everything is in the main drawable folder.

Comment: Have you checked what the android versions of the devices the crashes are occurring on are? Are they different than what you've tested on?

Comment: The versions are different, but the app was built for API 5.1, yet the error is occurring for mostly for 6.0

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your layout xml file. please verify your layout file.

Comment: I added in the layout file to my post. It runs fine on my end.

Comment: Try to run on device with minimum supported android version. I think you will get real cause for crash.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the minimum support SDK was 22, however the drawable icons I was using were for some reason only supported by SDK 24. So any devices on SDK 22 or 23 would crash on startup as they could not load in these drawables.

Solved by replacing the custom drawable icons with built in vector assets from Android Studio.